# Looping a Selenium Python script

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following script that opens a browser and logs in then closes the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Ie()
import time

x=4
for i in range(x):    
    browser.get("http://localhost:8080/customercareweb-prototype/")
    username=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@placeholder='Username']").send_keys("op1")
    password=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys("op1")
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='dlg-auth-button z-button']").click()
    browser.close()
```

When i run this i get the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

What am i doing wrong here. I just want to get this script to run for 4 times in a row.

Comment: Which line throws the error?  Also, I think you probably need to remove `username=` and `password=` (I don't think `send_keys` returns a value).

Comment: Please post the relevant traceback. I suspect it might not be related to your code but a problem in the selenium bindings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work wrapping it i a function. But i am still puzzled why i could not do it with simple "for" statement.

```
def login():
browser=webdriver.Ie()    
browser.get("http://localhost:8080/customercareweb-prototype/")
username=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@placeholder='Username']").send_keys("op1")
password=browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys("op1")
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='dlg-auth-button z-button']").click()

i=login()
for i in range(1):
login()
```